# Top margin isn't working

Tags: css

How can I get the `margin-top` to work? The `margin-left` works fine, however nothing is happening with `margin-top`

```css
p.ex1 {
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-left: 35px;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer2">

  <p class="ex1"> ABOUT US </p>

  <hr>


  <div class="footer">
    <br>
    <p id="top">
      <font size="5">Contact us</font>
    </p>
  </div>
```

Comment: `nothing is happening ` --> can you elaborate?

Comment: The top margin won't go down 15 px

Comment: Your `margin-top` is working perfectly fine. Maybe you're just not noticing it because `<p>` elements come with out of the box margins.

Comment: down from where? you have a background for the footer?

Comment: Left margin works if you remove the typo  **<p.ex1** => p.ex1

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your particular browser there is a default `top-margin` on a `p` tag. Here on Firefox that is 16px (probably derived from 1em) which is there before you add any CSS. So if you set `top-margin` to 15px, there is hardly a preceiveable difference. Still, it *does*  work - set it to 25px (or anything that is clearly different from 16px, or also to 0px to really see it *without*  any top-margin) and you'll see it.

In the following example I changed your snippet so that it displays the element *without*  a top-margin (i.e. I set it to zero). When you hover over it, the top-margin is set to 15px. There you see the difference...

```css
p.ex1 {
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-left: 35px;
}
p.ex1:hover {
  margin-top: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer2">

  <p class="ex1"> ABOUT US </p>

  <hr>


  <div class="footer">
    <br>
    <p id="top">
      <font size="5">Contact us</font>
    </p>
  </div>
```